# Mock reference objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

How do you avoid creating superfluous Strings when unit testing?

For example the String "SERIALIZED" seems a bit unnecessary and arbitrary..what would you use instead?

```
    Object update=new Object(); 
    FileWriter writer=mock(FileWriter.class);
    Serializer serializer=mock(Serializer.class);
    when(cache.getWriter(update)).thenReturn(writer);
    when(serializer.serialize(update)).thenReturn("SERIALIZED");

    FileRecorder recorder=new FileRecorder(serializer);
    recorder.receive(update);
    verify(writer).write("SERIALIZED");
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with this as-is.  You're not creating the string at unit test runtime, either -- it goes into the `String` pool, so it's only created once and always reused.

Comment: I don't quite see the problem. You could pull out the two occurrences of "SERIALIZED" into a constant or local variable to save duplication?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't call strings you use to verify whether your test passes *superfluous*. However, way you do it calls for a bit of refactoring:

- what `"SERIALIZED"` stands for? Will you be able to recall its purpose in, say, 2 months?
- you use same string twice, simple typo (which happen) will break your test. And that's something you want to avoid

I suggest refactoring it into a *test suite-wide* constant (or *test method-wide*, if that single test is only place you use it). And give it proper name:

```
final String FAKED_SERIALIZER_OUTPUT = "Any random content";
Object update=new Object(); 
FileWriter writer=mock(FileWriter.class);
Serializer serializer=mock(Serializer.class);
when(cache.getWriter(update)).thenReturn(writer);
when(serializer.serialize(update)).thenReturn(FAKED_SERIALIZER_OUTPUT);

FileRecorder recorder=new FileRecorder(serializer);
recorder.receive(update);
verify(writer).write(FAKED_SERIALIZER_OUTPUT);
```

Note that content of the string becomes irrelevant, considering variable name describes its purpose correctly.

Comment: so what should you put in as the random content? Empty string...Mock String?

Comment: @DD.: it doesn't really matter. Content can be random like I said - as long as it doesn't cause test to break (it shouldn't). You can use something more descriptive than `"Any random content"`, but I'd rather focus on variable name to deal with explaining what's the string about. Actual content is irrelevant.